# cordova build and mobileangularUi

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I made a simple app for my company using mobileAngularUi and on my computer everything works fine.

I tried to build an android app using cordova, then I installed the apk on my phone but when I run the app it only show the index.html without loading anything (so basically a white screen).

Do you know why does it happen? this is my first time using this framework (http://mobileangularui.com/)

Answer (score 0):

### Did you follow procedure on this link from there blog

**Installing and Scaffold**

```
npm install -g bower yo gulp generator-mobileangularui
npm install -g phonegap
phonegap create myAppName
cd myAppName
yo mobileangularui
```

**Build your project for the first time**

```
gulp build
```

**Run the application**

```
phonegap run ios # or android, or whatever is your target
```

[link is here](http://mobileangularui.com/blog/using-the-generator/)

Comment: thanks for advice, i will keep that in mind. i am kind for new to this community.